# JSTL c:forEach is not working in Facelets

Tags: jsf, jstl, facelets

I have a file called test.xhtml i am trying to access a hash map using foreach in Facelets, but it is not displaying key value pair my code is as follows. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

```
    <html xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<head>
    <title>JSTL Simple Conditional Execution Example</title>
</head>
<h:body>
    <f:view>
        <c:forEach var="nameMap" items="${specificationAutogege.details}">
            <p> ${nameMap.key}</p>
        </c:forEach>
    </f:view>
</h:body>
```

Is it possible to use JSTL in Facelets?

The HTML output is rendered as follows:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core">
<head>
    <title>JSTL Simple Conditional Execution Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <c:forEach var="nameMap" items="{Versnellingsk=A very long text come here, Kleur=ZWART Two, Model=3008, Carrosiere=5 deures MPV, A very long text come here=Date Here, BrandShoert=E, Type=3008 Hybrid4 2.0 HDi, Merk=Peugeot, Bowjaar=2011 Shortgate}" varstatus="true">
        <p/>
    </c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i am just trying to display key only .. but that one is not working. but same is working when i am using JSP template having .JSP extesnion .

Comment: are you using JSF2 ? try using this namespace `xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"`

Answer (score 12):

```
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
```

This JSTL XML namespace URI is specific to Facelets 1.x. JSF 2.x ships with Facelets 2.x which has a different JSTL XML namespace URI:

```
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
```

Since JSF 2.2 new XML namespace domain was introduced to remove old `sun.com` domain.

```
xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
```

#### See also:

- [Our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)
- [Which XML namespace to use with JSF 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31068678/which-xml-namespace-to-use-with-jsf-2-2)

Answer (score -1):

The xhtml extension suggests you're using JSF2 rather than JSF, hence you need to switch from using the ${} notation to #{} notation.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Both behave exactly the same when using JSF2 Facelets. Moreover, Facelets can be used together with JSF1, it only needs to be installed and configured separately.