# Which XML namespace to use with JSF 2.2 and up

Tags: jsf, facelets, jsf-2.2, xml-namespaces, java-ee-7

I have migrated my application from JSF 1.2 to 2.2.

It used XML namespaces on `java.sun.com` domain like  `xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"`. However, [Oracle's Java EE 7 tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/HTML5-JSF/html5jsf.html) is using XML namespaces on `xmlns.jcp.org` domain like 
`xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"`.

Which one is recommended and why was this changed?

Comment: Go with `http://xmlns.jcp.org/...`, if you are using JSF 2.2.x. It is a new JSF 2.2 thing (JSF 2.4 does not exist, by the way which you should have mistakenly typed in. It should be JSF 2.2.4 instead).

Comment: Jsf 2.4? Latest stable is 2.2 and 2.3 is in development. I think you are mixing things up. 2.2 already has the jcp namespace

Comment: Yes it's 2.2.4. It's a mistake when I typed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> *Which one is recommended?*

For Java EE 7 and 8, go ahead with XML namespaces on `xmlns.jcp.org` domain. This was newly introduced since Java EE 7 in 2013 (which covers a.o. JSF 2.2, Servlet 3.1, CDI 1.1, etc). Do note that this not only affects Facelets files, but also XML configuration files such as [`faces-config.xml`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-configure002.htm), [`web.xml`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-facelets003.htm#JEETT00910), [`beans.xml`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/cdi-adv001.htm#CACDCFDE), etc.

The old XML namespaces on `java.sun.com` are still there for backwards compatibility, but the support will eventually disappear in a future Java EE version. You should migrate your code base as soon as you can. It should be a trivial task using "find and replace in all files" facility offered by the average IDE.

Only older Mojarra 2.2.0 / 2.2.1 versions have had bugs related to the XML namespace changes, but those should not manifest in newer versions. See also a.o.

- [Using new xmlns.jcp.org namespace on composites causes java.lang.NullPointerException at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436511/using-new-xmlns-jcp-org-namespace-on-composites-causes-java-lang-nullpointerexce/)
- [f:viewParam doesn't pass required parameter when new xmlns.jcp.org namespace is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517384/fviewparam-doesnt-pass-required-parameter-when-new-xmlns-jcp-org-namespace-is/)
- [The metadata component needs to be nested within a f:metadata tag. Suggestion: enclose the necessary components within <f:metadata>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945943/the-metadata-component-needs-to-be-nested-within-a-fmetadata-tag-suggestion-e/)

---

> *and why was this changed?*

Because Java is not from Sun anymore since 2010. Note that they were smart to not make it `java.oracle.com` or something tight coupled to the currently owning company. It's now nicely and independently tied to the JCP ([Java Community Process](https://jcp.org/)), the one really responsible for managing the Java (EE) specifications.

<sup>*And then a few years later ...*</sup>

Since Java EE was taken over by Eclipse and rebranded to Jakarta EE, the XML namespace domain is changed from `xmlns.jcp.org` to `jakarta.ee` to make it further independent. Moreover, the specification process is also not anymore owned by JCP.

Faces 4 in Jakarta EE 10 has as per [spec issue 1553](https://github.com/jakartaee/faces/issues/1553) also taken a step further to not anymore use a URL as XML namespace URI, but a URN instead: `xmlns:f="jakarta.faces.core"`. The reason for using a URN instead of URL is because those taglib URIs are in first place not available as physical web resources returning some sort of XSD file and therefore only caused confusion among starters.

#### See also:

- [What are the namespaces for "h", "f", ... in a JSF page for Jakarta EE 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68438669/what-are-the-namespaces-for-h-f-in-a-jsf-page-for-jakarta-ee-9/)
- [Which role plays URI in identifying JSTL tag libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31291014/which-role-plays-uri-in-identifying-jstl-tag-libraries)

Comment: What changes needed in faces-config.xml, web.xml, beans.xml, etc? I did quick check and it seems to be working by just changing namespace. It would be helpful if you can share any suitable link.

Answer (score 13):

I made a brief summary of all the new official oracle namespaces:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:p="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
    xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite"
    xmlns:fn="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/functions"      
    xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf">

    <!-- Content here -->
</html>
```

I use this as template for all of my **.xhtml** files. Details can be found in the official facelet tag library: [JavaServer Faces 2.2 Facelets Tag Library Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/toc.htm)

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

*For future visitors having namespace confusion/issue:*

I would like to highlight the general way to find out which namespace to use:

- If you want to use tags from JSF HTML tag library or JSF core tag library then open the JSF implementation JAR (like Oracle Mojarra, Apache MyFaces- `myfaces-impl-2.3.1.jar`) and find the tag library's `.tld` or `.xml` file (you can find it under `META-INF` directory) and use the namespace mentioned over there.
- If you want to use the RichFaces or PrimeFaces then open their implementation JAR (like `richfaces-components-ui-4.0.0.Final.jar`, or `primefaces-6.2.jar`) and do same thing as above.

If implementation has `.tld` (like `rich.tld`) then you can use the value of `<uri>` element for example `<uri>http://richfaces.org/rich</uri>`. And if implementation has `.xml` (like `rich.taglib.xml`) then you can use the value of `<namespace>` element for example `<namespace>http://richfaces.org/rich</namespace>`

**What I have mentioned above is strictly related to JSF but holds good in general as well. Key thing is that if you use the namespace from the implementation JAR then you will never run into issues.**