# <h:inputfile> Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/html, but no tag was defined for name: inputfile tomcat8

Tags: maven, jsf, jsf-2

First of all this is my first post on stackoverflow , so if ever I have post something not conform to rules my appologies.

I am currently working with JSF 2.2 and servlet 3.0.1 with tomcat8. I want to implement an upload file functionality. I have gone through the net and found some appropriate code. However , i have encountered below error :
 **Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/html, but no tag was defined for name: inputFile**

I will appreciate if anyone could help on that. I have attached my pom.xml and the hello.xhtml

I will implement the backcode in a later stage.

Thanks for the support.

part of (pom.xml)

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
         <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
         <version>2.2.6</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
         <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-ri</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
         <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
     </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

xhtml:

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
      <h:head>
            <title>JSF 2.0 Hello World</title>
      </h:head>
      <h:body>
            <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">  
               <h:inputfile></h:inputfile> <br/>
               <h:inputfile></h:inputfile> <br/>
            </h:form>
     </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your code ???

Comment: just added..sorry new to stackflow..Having issue with posting the codes

Comment: In yout xhtml you use `inputfile` as you do in your title. In the error IN the question it states `inputFile`  (capital F). What do you actually use? if it is `inputfle` then change that to `inputFile`... and for further questions, JSF2.2 is an api version and the implementation is more relevant. See also http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info on how to post good questions from the beginning

Comment: and if using jsf 2.2, you can use the new namespace declarations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31068678/which-xml-namespace-to-use-with-jsf-2-2

Comment: thank you very much for your support. As said , i did a very stupid error it should be inputFile instead of inputfile.

Comment: but where did the inputFile (capital F) in the error in the post come from then? Copied/pasted from somewhere else? And btw a good IDE will signal these typos for you

Comment: I am currently using eclipse Luna as ide. Any other IDE that you can suggest?