# Passthrough not working

Tags: jsf-2.2, mojarra

I've tried a few different variations and none of them seem to be working.

Specs:

- Mojarra 2.2.5
- Primefaces 6.0
- JSF 2.2

1.) Passthrough

```
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ps="http://java.sun.com/jsf/passthrough"

....

<h:inputText id="sign_in_useremail" type="text" class="form-control" ps:placeholder="useremail" />
```

2.) PassThroughAttribute

---

```
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:pc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"

...
<h:inputText id="sign_in_useremail" type="text" class="form-control"">
   <pc:passThroughAttribute name="sign_in_useremail" value="useemail" />
</h:inputText>
```

---

3.) Long shot with just a label

```
<h:inputText id="sign_in_useremail" type="text" class="form-control" label="useremail">
```

Comment: Start by using the best/right/most recent namespaces for 2.2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31068678/which-xml-namespace-to-use-with-jsf-2-2

Comment: @Kukeltje Excellent, that solved my problem. You can make this answer and I'll accept it, up to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 1) you are using pre-2.2 namespaces, in 2) you have a mix of 2.2 and pre-2.2 namespaces. Just make them all 2.2 compliant.

**See also**

- [Which XML namespace to use with JSF 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31068678/which-xml-namespace-to-use-with-jsf-2-2)