# f:ajax does not render the outputPanel until I refresh

Tags: ajax, jsf, refresh

Every time I debug the application and type something in the Textbox, the Controller remember only when I refresh the page.
Without the ajax Tag it's working fine. So my guess: the rendering of the outputPanel does not Work. I set Breakpoints  (ajax listener and field setter are both called) and tested it many times and the outcome was the controller only works when i clicked the button and then refreshed the page. Referring JSF, I work with Eclipse for Java EE and Tomcat v.9.0 and earlier.

Strange thing is that the `execute` attribute only has the id for the `name` input in its `execute` attribute and still the listener is called (sysout is printed), this is not to be expected accordimg to #9 in [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not set/updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value). But changing it to `@form` does not change it

**new.xhtml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      >
    <h:head>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <h:form id="formID">
            <h:inputText id="name" value="#{LayoutController.name}"></h:inputText>

            <h:commandButton value="Welcome Me">
                <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{LayoutController.listen}" execute=":formID:name" render=":formID:output"/>
            </h:commandButton>

            <h:panelGroup id="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{LayoutController.name}"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**LayoutController.java:**

```
    package Template;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent;

@ManagedBean(name="LayoutController")
@SessionScoped
public class LayoutController{

    private String name;

    public LayoutController() {
        this.name="";
    }

    public String getName() {
       return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
    }

    public void listen (AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
        this.name = this.name + " ! ";
        System.out.println("Clicked");
    }


}
```

Comment: the page shall not refresh, it should load or render the panelGroup dynamically. but it only renders after refreshing the site and only works with @Sessionscoped.

Comment: For example with @Requestscoped it can not work because after refreshing the site the controller does not exist anymore

Comment: ooops, yes the listener is called ! and the click print works also fine

Comment: just the rendering...

Comment: i know the post and the solution with @form but for me it does not work.. I also tried in this code :formID:output etc. so annoying..

Comment: oh and i have jsf 2.3 you mean deleting the render?

Comment: why did you not mention you knew this? Would have saved me time asking etc...

Comment: Jsf 2.3 is an api version. Not real implementation version.  Can you fix https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31068678/which-xml-namespace-to-use-with-jsf-2-2/

Comment: oops sorry... noob move :D

Comment: No problem... glad you are responding. So many ask a question and are silent for one, two or even more days

Comment: I removed some comments and added some summary to your question. Can you validate?

Comment: how to validate..? ok so i just added jsf2.2 to my project and it does not work

Comment: validate my changes in your question. are they a correct summary from our comments. And I requested you to change the namespaces in your page,  not to change a jsf 2.3.x implementation for a 2.2.x one (what is your jsf implementation (mojarra or myfaces) and version btw)

Comment: Inside a form you may use simple ids like `execute='name'` or `render='output'`. Did you try simple ids? Did you look in the response data in your browser console? Is `<update id='formID:output'...` present?