# Configure IntelliJ to show warning/error on unregistered attribute of a JSF tag

Tags: jsf, intellij-idea, facelets

```
<h:outputText fantasyattribute="shouldRaiseError" value="#{elcondition}" />
```

How can I configure IntelliJ to provide an error or a warning on `fantasyattribute` in the above example? This attribute is not registered in the VDL of the `<h:outputText>` tag.

Comment: JSF tags are defined by  a specific taglib for instance If I keep ctrl pressed on outputText,  I got this spec from Intellij 

    <tag>
        <tag-name>outputText</tag-name>
        <attribute>
            <description>
                Converter instance registered with this component.
            </description>
            <name>converter</name>
            <required>false</required>
            <type>javax.faces.convert.Converter</type>
        </attribute>
 ... continue ... 

JSF 2.2.14, Intellij 2019.3.3

More at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_custom_tag.htm

Comment: Hi @Kukeltje what I'm looking for is this, in example you see outputText, fantasy attribute is not allowed in the taglib relative to outputText. 

So the relative taglib in this context is JSF/lib/jsf-support.jar!/resources/schemas/html_basic.taglib.xml in the http://java.sun.com/jsf/html namespace.

Isn't there any way on intellij to raise a warning if I use "fantasyattribute" like in that case? That would be nice if applies to all the components, with custom taglib i.j. should raise a warn if I put an attribute on a component that doesn't exists. But... I'm not able to find it in intelij

Comment: What is the 'taglib relative to outputText' ??? Or do you actually mean **RELATED** to outputtext? That would be waaaay more logical. Two things.... With  JSF 2.2.x you should use other namespaces, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31068678/which-xml-namespace-to-use-with-jsf-2-2-and-up 2: jsf-support.jar does not sound like a well known jar file for existing JSF implementations...

Comment: Ops... false friend for my language, related is right

Comment: Anyway, just tried to change the namespace to http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core and nothing changes, wrong attributes are not inspected and reported :(

Comment: This is because standard XML supports ALL attributes. Of course, an IDE should be able to be configured to behave otherwise. This is a valid question, I've only improved the bad English.

Comment: yes... that's a specialization of xml (xhtml), that is used for a purpose and tag are usefull only if existing behavior is match.

So Intellij doesn't have this feature like all the others editors? (I.e. Netbeans)

Edit. I see your edit @BalusC thanks for your edits in the title

Comment: I have no idea. I don't use IntelliJ.