# Failed to define class jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet

Tags: jsf, servlets, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I've got following error when I want to start *Wildfly* server:

> 09:26:10,548 WARN  [org.jboss.modules.define] (MSC service thread 1-1)
> Failed to define class jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet in Module
> "deployment.demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" from Service Module Loader:
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link...

But after I change (in *web.xml* file):

```
<servlet-class>jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
```

to

```
<servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
```

the error is gone.

I've tried it with both version **4.0.0** and **3.0.0** of **jakarta.faces-api** dependency:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.faces/jakarta.faces-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.faces-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And here is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd"
    version="5.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Based on [jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/3.0](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/3.0/apidocs/jakarta/faces/webapp/facesservlet) and [jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/4.0](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/4.0/apidocs/jakarta/faces/webapp/facesservlet) I can use jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet class, So why I got the error?

I'm using latest *Eclipse (Version: 2022-03 (4.23.0))* and *wildfly-26.1.0.Final*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [WildFly download page](https://www.wildfly.org/downloads/), `wildfly-26.1.0.Final` is **not** a Jakarta EE 9 server, let alone a Jakarta EE 10 server. It's a Jakarta EE 8 server.

[image]

Jakarta EE 8 in turn ships with [JSF 2.3](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/2.3/) (and [Servlet 4.0](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/)).
This means that you should be using `javax.faces.*` package and the `faces-config.xml` should be conform JSF 2.3 and `web.xml` should be conform Servlet 4.0.

You most probably intended to pick the [`wildfly-preview-26.1.0.Final`](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/releases/download/26.1.0.Final/wildfly-preview-26.1.0.Final.zip) download link, provided by the section above of it, specifically labeled as **Preview**. This one is a Jakarta EE 9 server which is the first one with Jakartified package names (i.e. `jakarta.*` instead of `javax.*`) and ships with [JSF 3.0](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/3.0/) (and [Servlet 5.0](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/)). The Jakarta EE 10 implementation will be provided by the upcoming WildFly 27.x, currently still in Alpha stage. It's going to provide [Faces 4.0](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/4.0/) (and [Servlet 6.0](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/6.0/)).

That said, your `pom.xml` is incorrect for a full fledged Jakarta EE server. You should never manually ship loose Jakarta EE artifacts such as JSF along with the webapp. You should declare the *entire* Jakarta EE dependency as `provided` instead of the individual JSF dependency as a physical JAR file enclosed in the WAR. Below one is for Jakarta EE 8:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

That's really all you need in `pom.xml`.

#### See also:

- [How to properly install and configure JSF libraries via Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081234/how-to-properly-install-and-configure-jsf-libraries-via-maven)
- [JSF 2.3 tutorial with WildFly and Eclipse](https://balusc.omnifaces.org/2020/04/jsf-23-tutorial-with-eclipse-maven.html)
- [What are the namespaces for "h", "f", ... in a JSF page for Jakarta EE 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68438669/what-are-the-namespaces-for-h-f-in-a-jsf-page-for-jakarta-ee-9/68439743#68439743)

Comment: So, now if im using Wildlfly 20.0.1FINAL, and im using jakartaee-api v.10